# How to load an image dataset in scikit-learn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have collected a group of images that I want to train a model on.

How do I load the image dataset? I have a folder of training data with two folders in it denoting the two different kinds of objects. How would I go about loading this data set and then training a model?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Unfortunately this is not a code-writing or tutorials service, and we ask that questions include a [mcve] including _code_ for what you've tried so far based on your own research, and what was wrong with your attempt(s)

Comment: @G.Anderson what do you mean by "*unfortunately*"?

Comment: @desertnaut I mean that, unfortunately for the OP, they can't get the specific type of help  they are requesting. It's a polite way of introducing this point to a new site user, attempting to be welcoming while still telling them that they need to rephrase the question

Answer (score 1):

this might help you to load your dataset into *data* variable from a single folder of images

```
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np
path = 'path to your dataset'
list_of_files = os.listdir(path)
data = np.empty(0)
for i in list_of_files:
    x = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path+i))
    data.append(x)
```